# increasing, decreasing, non-decreasing, non-increasing permutation/combination

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I have this question and I'm stuck:

> Q: In the set of three-digit integers {100,101,...,999}, how many integers are there
>
> (a) with three distinct digits that are either increasing (as in 257, 139) or decreasing (as in 752, 430)?
>
> (b) with three digits that are either non-decreasing (as in 477, 555, 123) or non-increasing (666,321,943)?
>
> (Note that digits may repeat.)

For part a) I got to 7 * **_ * _** as you know for the three digit number as 8, 9 cannot be the first digit, it would not make a three digit number however I don't know how to proceed because wouldn't the second digit vary from the first digit picked?

I would like to understand this as much as I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We solve the first problem. There is some complication because $0$ is not allowed as an initial digit.

So let us first count how many possibilities there are if we allow initial $0$. We can **choose** the $3$ digits in $\binom{10}{3}$ ways, and for each such choice we can arrange the digits in two orders, increasing or decreasing, for a total of $2\binom{10}{3}$.

Now we must take away the "bad" choices, the ones with initial digit $0$. There are $\binom{9}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ non-zero digits, and we can only use increasing order. So the number of bad choices is $\binom{9}{2}$. Thus the total number of good choices is $2\binom{10}{3}-\binom{9}{2}$.

For the second problem, one can count the *additional* possibilities that are produced by allowing equality.

Comment: Hi @Andre Nicolas, I was wondering how there are 2 non-zero digits? I got confused there .. Thanks!

Comment: In the subtraction part, I am counting the number of strings of the type $0xy$, where $0\lt x\lt y$, which got counted among the $2\binom{10}{3}$, but should not be counted, because they give us numbers less than $100$. So we need to choose the two digits $x$ and $y$, where $x,y$ are taken from the digits $1$ to $9$. There are $\binom{9}{2}$ ways to choose them.

Answer (score 0):

> In the set of positive three-digit integers $\{100, 101, \ldots, 909\}$, how many integers are there with three distinct digits that are either increasing or decreasing?

A three-digit positive integer with strictly increasing digits corresponds to a selection of three of the nine digits in the string $123456789$.  For instance, the selection $1\color{blue}{2}34\color{blue}{5}6\color{blue}{7}89$ corresponds to selecting the number $257$.  Thus, the number of three-digit positive integers with strictly increasing digits is $\binom{9}{3}$.

A three-digit positive integer with strictly decreasing digits corresponds to a selection of three of the ten digits in the string $9876543210$.  For instance, the selection $98765\color{blue}{43}21\color{blue}{0}$ corresponds to selecting the number $430$.  The number of three-digit positive integers with distinct decreasing digits is $\binom{10}{3}$.

Since the two cases are mutually exclusive, the number of positive three-digit integers with distinct digits that are either increasing or decreasing is 
$$\binom{9}{3} + \binom{10}{3}$$

> In the set of positive three-digit integers $\{100, 101, \ldots, 999\}$, how many integers are there with three digits that are non-decreasing or non-increasing?

**Hint:**  A three-digit positive integer with non-decreasing digits is completely determined by how many times each digit appears.  For instance, if $3$ appears twice and $2$ appears once, then the number must be $233$ since the digits are non-decreasing.